# PIG : count of each product in distinctive Locations

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to do following Step1 to Step4 in pig:

```
STEP 1:- Create a user table:and take data from /tmp/users.txt-
        |Column 1 | USER ID |int|
        |Column 2 |EMAIL|chararray|
        |Column 3 |LANGUAGE |chararray|
        |Column 4 |LOCATION |chararray|

 STEP 2:- Crate a transaction table and take data from /tmp/transaction.txt:-
        |Column 1 | ID |int|
        |Column 2 |PRODUCT|int|
        |Column 3 |USER ID |int|
        |Column 4 |PURCHASE AMOUNT |double|
        |Coulmn 5 |DESCRIPTION |chararray|

 Step 3:- Find out the count of each product in distinctive Locations.
 Step 4:- Display the results.
```

For achieving above I did the following :

```
 users = LOAD '/tmp/users.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (USERID:int, EMAIL:chararray, LANGUAGE:chararray, LOCATION: chararray);
 trans = LOAD '/tmp/transaction.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID:int, PRODUCT:int, USERID:int, PURCHASEAMOUNT: double, DESCRIPTION: chararray);
 users_trans = JOIN users BY USERID RIGHT, trans BY USERID;

 B = GROUP users_trans BY (DESCRIPTION,LOCATION);
 C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as comb, COUNT(users_trans) AS Total;
 DUMP C;
```

But, I am getting errors.. It will helpful if you assist as I am new to pig.

```
   ##########################################
   Dataset

   user.txt
   1       creator@gmail.com       EN      US
   2       creator@gmail.com       EN      GB
   3       creator@gmail.com       FR      FR
   4       creator@gmail.com       IN      HN
   5       creator@gmail.com       PAK     IS

   transaction.txt

   1       1       1       300     a jumper
   2       1       2       300     a jumper
   3       1       5       300     a jumper
   4       2       3       100     a rubber chicken
   5       1       3       300     a jumper
   6       5       4       500     a soapbox
   7       3       3       200     a adhesive
   8       4       1       300     a lotion
   9       4       4       500     a sweater
   10      5       4       600     a jeans
```

```
Error Log:
2019-12-27 06:17:22,180 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader - Current split being processed file:/tmp/temp2029752934/tmp-883821114/part-r-00000:0+130
2019-12-27 06:17:22,242 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2019-12-27 06:17:22,242 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2019-12-27 06:17:22,242 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - soft limit at 83886080
2019-12-27 06:17:22,242 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2019-12-27 06:17:22,242 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2019-12-27 06:17:22,244 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2019-12-27 06:17:22,248 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
2019-12-27 06:17:22,248 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,250 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: C[7,4],B[6,4] C: C[7,4],B[6,4] R: C[7,4]
2019-12-27 06:17:22,254 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -
2019-12-27 06:17:22,254 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Starting flush of map output
2019-12-27 06:17:22,254 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Spilling map output
2019-12-27 06:17:22,254 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - bufstart = 0; bufend = 100; bufvoid = 104857600
2019-12-27 06:17:22,254 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214360(104857440); length = 37/6553600
2019-12-27 06:17:22,262 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: C[7,4],B[6,4] C: C[7,4],B[6,4] R: C[7,4]
2019-12-27 06:17:22,264 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Finished spill 0
2019-12-27 06:17:22,265 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task:attempt_local1424814286_0002_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2019-12-27 06:17:22,266 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -map
2019-12-27 06:17:22,266 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task 'attempt_local1424814286_0002_m_000000_0' done.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,266 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -Finishing task: attempt_local1424814286_0002_m_000000_0
2019-12-27 06:17:22,266 [Thread-18] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map task executor complete.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,266 [Thread-18] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Waiting for reduce tasks
2019-12-27 06:17:22,267 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task: attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0
2019-12-27 06:17:22,272 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2019-12-27 06:17:22,272 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2019-12-27 06:17:22,274 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task -  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
2019-12-27 06:17:22,274 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask - Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@2582aa54
2019-12-27 06:17:22,275 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl - MergerManager: memoryLimit=652528832, maxSingleShuffleLimit=163132208, mergeThreshold=430669056, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
2019-12-27 06:17:22,275 [EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.EventFetcher - attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
2019-12-27 06:17:22,276 [localfetcher#2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.LocalFetcher - localfetcher#2 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local1424814286_0002_m_000000_0 decomp: 14 len: 18 to MEMORY
2019-12-27 06:17:22,277 [localfetcher#2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput - Read 14 bytes from map-output for attempt_local1424814286_0002_m_000000_0
2019-12-27 06:17:22,277 [localfetcher#2] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl - closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 14, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->14
2019-12-27 06:17:22,277 [EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.EventFetcher - EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
2019-12-27 06:17:22,278 [Readahead Thread #3] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.io.ReadaheadPool - Failed readahead on ifile
EBADF: Bad file descriptor
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posix_fadvise(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX$CacheManipulator.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ReadaheadPool$ReadaheadRequestImpl.run(ReadaheadPool.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-12-27 06:17:22,278 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - 1 / 1 copied.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,280 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl - finalMerge called with 1 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
2019-12-27 06:17:22,280 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger - Merging 1 sorted segments
2019-12-27 06:17:22,280 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 7 bytes
2019-12-27 06:17:22,281 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl - Merged 1 segments, 14 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
2019-12-27 06:17:22,281 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl - Merging 1 files, 18 bytes from disk
2019-12-27 06:17:22,281 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl - Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
2019-12-27 06:17:22,281 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger - Merging 1 sorted segments
2019-12-27 06:17:22,281 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger - Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 7 bytes
2019-12-27 06:17:22,282 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - 1 / 1 copied.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,283 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
2019-12-27 06:17:22,283 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2019-12-27 06:17:22,284 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - Selected heap (PS Old Gen) of size 699400192 to monitor. collectionUsageThreshold = 489580128, usageThreshold = 489580128
2019-12-27 06:17:22,285 [pool-9-thread-1] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,286 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapReduce$Reduce - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: C[7,4],B[6,4] C: C[7,4],B[6,4] R: C[7,4]
2019-12-27 06:17:22,287 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task:attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
2019-12-27 06:17:22,289 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - 1 / 1 copied.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,289 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
2019-12-27 06:17:22,292 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - Saved output of task 'attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0' to file:/tmp/temp2029752934/tmp726323435/_temporary/0/task_local1424814286_0002_r_000000
2019-12-27 06:17:22,292 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - reduce > reduce
2019-12-27 06:17:22,292 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Task 'attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0' done.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,292 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Finishing task: attempt_local1424814286_0002_r_000000_0
2019-12-27 06:17:22,292 [Thread-18] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - reduce task executor complete.
2019-12-27 06:17:22,460 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local1424814286_0002
2019-12-27 06:17:22,460 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases B,C
2019-12-27 06:17:22,460 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: C[7,4],B[6,4] C: C[7,4],B[6,4] R: C[7,4]
2019-12-27 06:17:22,463 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,464 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,465 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,471 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2019-12-27 06:17:22,474 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
2.9.2   0.16.0  root    2019-12-27 06:17:20     2019-12-27 06:17:22     HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY

Success!

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime      MinMapTime      AvgMapTime      MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime        Alias   Feature Outputs
job_local1289071959_0001        2       1       n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a  trans,users,users_trans  HASH_JOIN
job_local1424814286_0002        1       1       n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a     n/a  B,C      GROUP_BY,COMBINER       file:/tmp/temp2029752934/tmp726323435,

Input(s):
Successfully read 5 records from: "/tmp/users.txt"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/tmp/transaction.txt"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 1 records in: "file:/tmp/temp2029752934/tmp726323435"

Counters:
Total records written : 1
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_local1289071959_0001        ->      job_local1424814286_0002,
job_local1424814286_0002


2019-12-27 06:17:22,475 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,476 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,477 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,485 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,486 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,487 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metricswith processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,492 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED 15 time(s).
2019-12-27 06:17:22,493 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Encountered Warning ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 55 time(s).
2019-12-27 06:17:22,493 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2019-12-27 06:17:22,496 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2019-12-27 06:17:22,496 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2019-12-27 06:17:22,503 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input files to process : 1
2019-12-27 06:17:22,503 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2019-12-27 06:17:22,541 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 2 seconds and 965 milliseconds (2965 ms)
```

Comment: Please show the errors you're getting and the actual datasets

Comment: I have included the datasets and error log..

Comment: Okay, I see no errors, only info and warn... But why are you trying to use PigStorage(',') if your data has no commas? Have you tried just running `pig` itself and individually running each line and dumping the results? Are you getting data you expect?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried without commas as well. But, I am not getting theresult. The objective is to get, count of each product in distinctive locations..

Comment: Can you update the question to include the attempt without using commas?

Answer (score 3):

## Advice

First of all: It seems that you are starting up with Pig. It may be valuable to know that Cloudera recently decided to deprecate Pig. It will of course not cease to exist, but think twice if you are planning to pick up a new skill or implement new use cases. I would recommend looking into Hive/Spark/Impala as more future proof alternatives.

## Answer

Your job succeeds, but presumably not with output you want. There are several hints to what may be wrong (data types/field names) however this does not point at a specific problem in the code.

My recommendation would be to find out where the problem exactly occurs. Simply cut off the end of your code and print an intermediate result to see if you are still on track.

In the (likely) event you have a problem in your load statement already, it is worth noting that you can still narrow it down further. First load, and then apply the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Given the data you have, first problem would be that you have no commas, so you must load the lines as a whole, then split them later. I used two or more spaces in the transactions file because your last column appears to be one string containing spaces. For accuracy, I suggest having a better delimiter than spaces/tabs.

Then the group by needs to reference the relations that the data comes from.

Everything else is fine, I think, though I'm not sure about the `COUNT(X)`

```
A = LOAD '/tmp/users.txt' USING PigStorage() as (line:chararray);
USERS = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '\\s+')) AS (userid:int,email:chararray,language:chararray,location:chararray);

B = LOAD '/tmp/transactions.txt' USING PigStorage() as (line:chararray);
TRANS = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '\\s\\s+')) AS (id:int,product:int,userid:int,purchase:double,desc:chararray);

X = JOIN USERS BY userid RIGHT, TRANS BY userid;
X_grouped = GROUP X BY (TRANS::desc, USERS::location);
RES = FOREACH X_grouped GENERATE group as comb, COUNT(X) AS Total;
\d RES;
```

#### Output

```
((a jeans,HN),1)
((a jumper,FR),1)
((a jumper,GB),1)
((a jumper,IS),1)
((a jumper,US),1)
((a lotion,US),1)
((a soapbox,HN),1)
((a sweater,HN),1)
((a adhesive,FR),1)
((a rubber chicken,FR),1)
```